# The output of mongo is non-deterministic with native-ruby-mongo-mapper

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I ran into a problem that happens randomly.

First, `exsit?(collection, id)` returned `true`

> it means there is already has an document in MongoDB, so I have to do further check in the next step

Then `(coll.find({_id: id}).first['history'].last['price']` will raise  the error

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for nil:NilClass>
```

I don't get why this happens randomly.

## Code

```
  def exsit?(collection, id)
    return (collection.find({_id: id}).first.nil? ) ? false : true
  end

  def is_price_changed?(coll, id, current_price)
      if exsit?(coll, id)
        return (coll.find({_id: id}).first['history'].last['price'] != current_price)? true : false
      else
        return true
      end    
  end
```

## This is my document format

```
{
  "updated_at": new Date(1435757280839),
  "price": 16890,
  "history": [
    {
      "updated_at": new Date(1435757277672),
      "price": 16890
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: are you running a single mongodb instance or a sharded cluster?

Comment: @bridiver Hi its single instance.

Comment: We saw issues like that when using more than one server, but not on a single instance

Comment: Yes, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 'history' attribute of that id is nil